# Sum of list arguments using currying in scala

Tags: scala, currying

I am trying to get the sum of arguments using currying in Scala. This is a very basic question so please don't go hard on it.

If you can answer the question then please otherwise let it be:

```
  object MultiSum extends App {

      var res=0

         def sum(f:Int=>Int)(x:Int*)={f(x)}

         val a=List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)

         val b=sum(x=>x+x)(a:_*)
    }
```

So `val b` will be storing the result of all the numbers passed in the List in `var a`

Thanks.

Comment: This question makes no sense, Please elaborate on your question

Comment: Where is the question ??

Answer (score 2):

Well... first of all... I think you should call your function `collect` and not `sum`. Now, lets help you write this `collect`.

So... your `collect` function takes two arguments,

1 - A `collector` function.
2 - Things to accumulate.

So... your collector function needs to know two things... first is already `collected` and second is next item to collect... and it will produce the next collected.

Which means that for collection of `Int`, your `collector` function will have a signature `(Int, Int) => Int`.

So, your collect function should have following signature,

```
def collect(collector: (Int, Int) => Int)(items: Int*): Int = ???
```

Now... lets come to implement it.

1 - Using `reduce`

```
def collect(collector: (Int, Int) => Int)(items: Int*): Int =
  items.reduce(collector)
```

2 - Using `fold`

```
def collect(collector: (Int, Int) => Int)(items: Int*): Int =
  items.fold(0)(collector)
```

Now, you can use it like this,

```
val l = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)

val b = collect((i1, i2) => i1 + i2)(l: _*)
```